# Getting "While resolving: undefined@undefined" error when importing Lottie

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

I am trying to import Lottie for react native and expo, and am an absolute beginner to this. I have this version of react-native installed: 4.14.0

I don't understand what "While resolving: undefined@undefined means? But I guess that I am having conflicting versions.

```
$ npm i --save lottie-react-native
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@16.8.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.8.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from lottie-react-native@3.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/lottie-react-native
npm ERR!     lottie-react-native@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.9.0" from react-native@0.61.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"^0.61.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@">=0.46" from lottie-react-native@3.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/lottie-react-native
npm ERR!     lottie-react-native@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\carol\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\carol\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-06T18_50_38_327Z-debug.log

//DEPENDENCIES from package.json: 

 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli-hermes": "^4.13.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-server-api": "^5.0.1-alpha.2",
    "anser": "^2.0.1",
    "braces": "^3.0.2",
    "error-stack-parser": "^2.0.6",
    "expo": "^40.0.1",
    "expo-sensors": "^9.2.0",
    "mem": "^8.1.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "node-stream-zip": "^1.13.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.64.0",
    "react-native-google-fonts": "^0.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.15.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "use-subscription": "^1.5.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Expo environment you have to install Lottie differently [via](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/lottie/):

```
expo install lottie-react-native
```

If not already done, please remove the entry of lottie-react-native and install it via expo. It should work like this.

Can you replace the following Package.json entries with:

"react": "16.13.1",

"react-dom": "16.13.1",

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.0.tar.gz",

I think that the React version is not compatible with the Expo React Native version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I uninstalled lottie-react-native and tried installing via `expo install lottie-react-native`. But I am still getting the same answer "Unable to resolve dependency tree" etc. and below in red: npm exited with non-zero code: 1

Comment: @Caroline I have edited my answer. Can you please revise the package.json as you see on my answer above?

Comment: I did as proposed and downgraded react and react-dom to 16.13.1 but there were still a lot of issues. I will try out Lottie in a React project instead, but not in this React-native one.